# Euler's proof of $\frac{\pi}{6}=1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-\cdots$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, analytic-number-theory, l-functions, dirichlet-series

Euler proved

> $$\frac{\pi}{6}=1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-\cdots$$
> where the reasoning of the signs thus is prepared, so that of the second may be had as $-$, prime numbers of the form $4m-1$ have a $-$ sign, prime numbers of the form $4m+1$ a $+$ sign, but composite numbers have that sign which agrees with the account of the multiplication from the primes.

He proved it by combining
$$\frac{\pi}{4}=\prod_{p\,\text{prime},p\gt 2}\frac{1}{1-(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}p^{-1}}$$
(which is a special case of the Euler product of the Dirichlet beta function)
with
$$\frac{1}{(1-az)(1-bz)(1-cz)\cdots}=1+Az+Bz^2+\cdots$$
where
$$A=\text{sum of the individual terms},$$
$$B=\text{sum of the two factors at a time},$$
etc. with the same factors not excluded, and set $z=1$.

But, there is one problem with Euler's proof. He is multiplying infinitely many geometric series and collecting like powers – treating it like polynomial multiplication, this surely requires some justification; can we prove that the factors in
$$\frac{1}{(1-az)(1-bz)(1-cz)\cdots}$$
(where $a,b,c,\ldots$ are the signed reciprocal primes) can be arbitrarily rearranged? It seems challenging because the product for $4/\pi$ is only *conditionally* convergent, hence the argument for rearrangement based on absolute convergence doesn't work here.

Euler is not very rigorous and I can't figure it out myself – how to save Euler's proof? Can we repair it with modern tools?

This question was also asked on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4818471/eulers-proof-of-frac-pi6-1-frac12-frac13-frac14-frac15

Comment: There was a small error in my response that I fixed now. Convergence of $F(s)$ in $\{s:\Re(s)>0\}$ is not uniform but locally uniform.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider the Dirichlet series
$$F(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{f(n)}{n^s},$$
where $f(n)$ is the completely multiplicative function which satisfies $f(2)=-1$ and $f(p)=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$ for odd primes $p$. For $\Re(s)>1$, this series converges absolutely, and it has the absolutely convergent Euler product decomposition
$$F(s)=\frac{1}{1+2^{-s}}\prod_p\frac{1}{1-\chi(p)p^{-s}}=\frac{1}{1+2^{-s}}L(s,\chi),\qquad\Re(s)>1,$$
where $\chi$ is the nontrivial Dirichlet character modulo $4$.

The key thing to observe is that the Dirichlet series $F(s)$ converges locally uniformly for $\Re(s)>0$. Indeed, this follows from Abel summation upon noting that
$$\left|\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}f(n)\right|=\left|\sum_{0\leq k\leq\log_2 x}(-1)^k\sum_{1\leq m\leq x/2^k}\chi(m)\right|\leq 1+\log_2 x,\qquad x\geq 1.$$
As a result, $F(s)$ defines a holomorphic function in the half-plane $\Re(s)>0$, and by the uniqueness principle, it factors there as $(1+2^{-s})^{-1}L(s,\chi)$. In particular,
$$F(1)=\frac{2}{3}L(1,\chi)=\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{6}.$$